# How do you enclose unknown HTML in a div with plain Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML page that has varying types of content. I would like to make a javascript function that when run encloses anything inside the `<body>` tag with a `<div id="content-container">`. Then I want to be able to add a `<div id="verifying"></div>` that new `<div>`. I think I know how to do this with jQuery, but I need to do it with plain Javascript.

Any idea as to how this would be done?

Comment: Not sure about the part after `verifying`, but what have you tried? DOM methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I might do it.

```
var body = document.body;

var contentContainer = document.createElement('div');
contentContainer.id = 'content-container';

var node;

while (node = body.firstChild) {
    contentContainer.appendChild(node);
}

body.appendChild(contentContainer);

var verifying = document.createElement('div');
verifying.id = 'verifying';
contentContainer.appendChild(verifying);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rsGSk/).

Comment: Why not simply `document.body.innerHTML = '<div id="content-container">' + document.body.innerHTML + '</div>';`? Unless he wants to keep all of his events...

Comment: @JosephSilber: Why wouldn't he want to keep all his events? Not to mention the overhead of serialising the entire `body` element and then un-serialising it again unnecessarily.

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much. I have learned probably more from your little snippet of plain Javascript there than I have from the books I have read on Javascript (They taught me how to do jQuery not Javascript :( ).

Comment: @Joseph - because moving the elements will keep all the non–inline listeners, it's very much more efficient, it keeps any references that might have been stored and innerHTML isn't fully consistent across browsers.

Comment: @chromedude - you will not learn javascript using jQuery. If you learn javascript, will learn a lot about how to use jQuery efficiently.

Comment: @RobG Yeah - I compltely agree that I need to learn plain Javascript. Most of what I have learned of it has been from asking questions and looking up how to do things online. The thing that stunted me with Javascript was the book I bought to learn it. It started me off immediately using jQuery. After reading the book I went back and tried to learn plain javascript, but I don't have a very good knowledge of it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested, but I imagine that you can take the innerHTML of document and set it to be itself along with whatever wrapper string (or div) you want.

Something along the lines of:

```
body = methodToLocateBodyInTheDom();
body.innerHTML = "<div id='content-container'>" + body.innerHTML + "</div>"
```

There are probably better ways, but I think something of that nature sure work.

Comment: That will lose all dynamically added listeners and different browsers will create different innerHTML strings for non-trivial content that may affect the reconstructed DOM.